# Background Mode doesn't be added for release in Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

I want to add Background Modes capability to all build modes but I can't. But it was added for debug and profile modes. When I choose release tab and click capability and background modes, nothing happens. Any solutions ?

info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by myself - make sure info.plist file in the build settings are not empty.

[image]